# When should you push new content for Newsstand apps?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, newsstand-kit

I read that we can only push a notification with a new content notification [once every 24 hours](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2280/_index.html).

But when should we push it? I'd imagine if a person has a WiFi only device it might not have any internet connection during the day, or the battery is low.

Should I schedule it at the time when the device is likely to be charged and with an internet connection? Like 3am in the morning? Then should I schedule it for every timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read it - it's a matter of iOS only initiating a download once every 24-hours, not a matter of the push.

If you create a push notification, it will be delivered to the device when it has a connection, so trying to time a push when the device is connected isn't necessary